# Find limit of a trig function

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I just started learning about limits and I need help with finding the limit of this problem.

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi} \, \tan\left(\frac{5x}{6}\right)
$$

I know that $\pi$ is in the domain and that the limit would be $0$ at $\pi$ from looking the graph $y=\tan x$.

Am I correct with that?

Sadly, I don't know what to do with that information. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: oops, added it in.

Comment: What happens if you replace $x$ with pi ?

Comment: It becomes 5$\pi$/6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tan(x)$ is a continuos function for $x \neq \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$

So $$\lim_{x \to \pi} \tan{\frac{5x}{6}} = \tan{\frac{5\pi}{6}}$$

This is because a function is continuos in a point $x_0$ iff $$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$$

Your observation is wrong: in fact it is true that the graph of $\tan x$ thouches $0$ in $x = \pi$, but your function is not $\tan x$. Try plotting with wolfram alpha the graph of $\tan{\frac{5x}{6}} $ and you'll see the difference.

Comment: I understand what you mean but still don't know how I would go about solving it.

Comment: about solving what? $\tan\frac{5\pi}{6}$ is a number, you're done. It's like 1, or $e$. Of course it indeed equal $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, but it is not required to express it that way

Comment: Oh, I thought you had to express a different way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using the continuity argument we have

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi} \, \tan\left(\frac{5x}{6}\right)=\tan\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)
$$
and since the $\tan$ function is $\pi-$ periodic then
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi} \, \tan\left(\frac{5x}{6}\right)=-\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=-\frac1{\sqrt3}
$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got $\pi$/6. Sorry my trigonometry is not that great.

Comment: $ \tan (\pi - \theta) \ = \ -\tan (\theta) \ . $

Comment: @yayu You know about the unit circle?

Comment: I do know about the unit circle.